# Primes which ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ramification

> Find all primes $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ which ramify in $K:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10})$.

For $\alpha:=\sqrt[3]{10}$, I used the fact that $d(1,\alpha,\alpha^2)=(\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])^2d_K$ to have some idea of which primes divide $d_K$.

According to my calculations, $d(1,\alpha,\alpha^2)=-2^23^35^2$, so every prime which ramifies in $K$ is necessarily in $\{2,3,5\}$.

How could I verify which among $2,3,5$ ramify?

If there's a better strategy to solve this, I'd also love to hear it.

Thank you!

Comment: One can even show that a prime divides the discriminant of an extension if *and only if* it ramifies in this extension.

Comment: @k.stm I know that, but I've only proved that $d_K$ is a divisor of $-2^23^35^2$, which means I still don't know exactly what $d_K$ is.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn’t read the question well enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $\rho=\sqrt[3]{10}$. The minimal polynomial for $\sigma=\frac{1+\rho+\rho^2}3$ is $X^3-X^2-3X-3$, so that $\sigma$ is an algebraic integer in $K$, and $\{1,\rho,\sigma\}$ seems to be an integral basis for the integers of $K$.

I think you’ll find that the discriminant with respect to this basis is $300=2^2\cdot3\cdot5^2$. Since finding a *larger* basis of the integers of $K$ would divide this discriminant by a square, and since it’s obvious that two and five have to ramify, it follows that $300$ it is; in particular, the $\Bbb Q$-basis of $K$ that I’ve chosen above must be an integral basis.

Comment: How did you find the magic $\sigma$ so easily? And why is it obvious that $2$ and $5$ should ramify? (of course I believe you, I just want to know how to do stuff as elegantly as that)

Comment: Question 1: experience, a lifetime of hand computation, paper and pencil. Question 2: Two and five have to ramify because you’re adjoining something that has $v_2(\rho)=1/3$ and $v_5(\rho)=1/3$. After all, $X^3-10$ is Eisenstein with respect to $2$ and $5$.